# Distribution Graph

Tags: python, excel

I would like to show the distribution of Income based on location and whether that user left or not. For this task which graph should I use. How can I show the distribution of numeric columns according to 2 other categorical columns?
[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You might want to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to get an idea about how to ask good questions.  You appear to have tagged matplotlib as library.  Did you already search for similar questions?   You also might want to try seaborn. E.g. `sns.violinplot(data=df, x='Location', y='Income', hue='Left', split=True, scale_hue=False)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [**`seaborn.FacetGrid`**](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html) in order to quickly organize a subplot with two columns: one for users who left and the other for the ones who didn't. Then you can use a hue in order to distinguish locations:

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(data = df, col = 'Left', hue = 'Location')
g.map(sns.histplot, 'Income').add_legend()
```

### Complete code

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np


base = {'Germany': 120000, 'France': 100000, 'Spain': 80000}

def func(df):
    return base[df['Location']] + 10000*np.random.randn() - df['Left']*5000*np.random.randn()

N = 1000
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Location'] = np.random.choice(a = ['France', 'Germany', 'Spain'], size = N)
df['Left'] = np.random.choice(a = [0, 1], size = N)
df['Income'] = df.apply(func, axis = 1)


g = sns.FacetGrid(data = df, col = 'Left', hue = 'Location')
g.map(sns.histplot, 'Income').add_legend()

plt.show()
```

[image]

---

Another solution, suggested by @JohanC in the comment, is to use a violinplot, where on x axis you have different locations and on y axis the income, using the hue in order to distinguish users who left and the other for the ones who didn't (moreover violins are splitted by hue in two halves):

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

sns.violinplot(ax = ax, data = df, x = 'Location', y = 'Income', hue = 'Left', split = True)

plt.show()
```

[image]

---

If you are not allowed to use `seaborn`, you can achieve a similar result of the first example by using only `matplotlib` through a loop over different locations:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2, sharex = 'all', sharey = 'all', figsize = (8, 4))

for location in df['Location'].unique():
    ax[0].hist(x = df[(df['Location'] == location) & (df['Left'] == 0)]['Income'], label = location, alpha = 0.7, edgecolor = 'black')
    ax[1].hist(x = df[(df['Location'] == location) & (df['Left'] == 1)]['Income'], label = location, alpha = 0.7, edgecolor = 'black')

ax[0].set_title('Left = 0')
ax[1].set_title('Left = 1')
ax[0].set_xlabel('Income')
ax[1].set_xlabel('Income')
ax[0].set_ylabel('Count')
ax[1].legend(title = 'Location', loc = 'upper left', bbox_to_anchor = (1.05, 1))

plt.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Hey thanks for your fast answer brother. It completely meets my need. Is there any way to do this in matplotlib? Cause I am not allowed to use seaborn :(

Comment: @Zephyr Let me also thank you for doing someone's possible homework question...

Comment: @Baruk Albayrak I updated my answer in order to draw a plot by using only `matplotlib`